# Datatable script not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

Following is my script of bootstrap datatable. Script has three parts of three functions. 
Daterange picker and datatable and clear filter. 
My problem is that when daterange picker and clear filter scripts works, Datatable not runs. and when both are commented datatable works fine.

```
<script>
    //daterange picker and filter both
    var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';
        var datepickerDefaults = {
            showTodayButton: true,
            showClear: true
        };
        $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
            {column_number: 12, filter_type: "range_date", datepicker_type: 'bootstrap-datetimepicker', date_format: 'DD-MMM-YY', filter_plugin_options: datepickerDefaults}
        ]);
        SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    });

    //datatable 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['excel'],
            lengthChange: true,
            paging: false,
            scrollY: 535,
            scrollX: false,
            sScrollXInner: "190%",
            "oLanguage": {"sSearch": "Search"},
            "columnDefs": [
                {"sClass": "datecol", "aTargets": [12]},
                {"orderable": false, "aTargets": [13]},
                {"orderable": false, "aTargets": [14]},
                {"orderable": false, "aTargets": [15]},
            ],
            "order": [[12, "desc"]],
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns().every(function (currentValue) {
                    if (currentValue !== 15 & currentValue !== 14 & currentValue !== 13) {
                        var column = this;
                        var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                                .css('width', 60)
                                .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                                .on('change', function () {
                                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                            $(this).val()
                                            );
                                    column
                                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                            .draw();
                                });
                        column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    // Clear filtered data
    $.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        fnInitComplete: function (oSettings, json) {
            // Add "Clear Filter" button to Filter
            var btnClear = $('<button class="btnClearDataTableFilter">clear</button>');
            btnClear.appendTo($('#' + oSettings.sTableId).parents('.dataTables_wrapper').find('.dataTables_filter'));
            $('#' + oSettings.sTableId + '_wrapper .btnClearDataTableFilter').click(function () {
                $('#' + oSettings.sTableId).dataTable().fnFilter('');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you produce a demo?